# Spring Idea for Dynamic URL Builder

Tags: java, spring, url, builder

Recently i got a request from my immediate superior to build a dynamic url builder in spring. The aim of having this builder is to concatenate a base url with relative path of resources(images, json files, etc) so that it will form a full path.

Currently we provide the images using relative paths like `/images/avatar/default_avatar.jpg`, but i want it to be in full path, `http://www.test.net/images/avatar/default_avatar.jpg`

I searched online for the builder design, but can't find any, perhaps i searched for the wrong keyword, so i don't know where to start.

My initial idea is, to keep the base path in a `.properties` file so that i can use it for concatenation in the builder.

Any constructive ideas/good practices for the builder design is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide more details cause " url builder in spring" is not clear what you mean. If you have HttpServletRequest just do HttpServletRequest.getScheme() if not use InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()

I'm just guessing as no any code provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any constructive ideas/good practices for the builder design is appreciated.

You might want to take a look at `UriComponentsBuilder` from Spring, you can explicitly specify scheme type, host, etc. The  advantage of `UriComponentsBuilder` is the ability to  inject it directly into a controller method. You can view [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder) for more information.

> The aim of having this builder is to concatenate a base url with relative path of resources(images, json files, etc) so that it will form a full path.

I believe you can easily achieve that, without any `.properties` file